# Howto enable rpy2 in python using ports?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, macports, rpy2

I know that there are several questions touching this problem, but I can hardly figure out, if there is one solution for my problem. I am using Mac 10.6.8, MacPorts 2.1.3.
Here I refer to [one discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687939/how-to-install-rpy2-on-mac-os-x), where my issue seems to be addressed. This is, what I have done:

```
$ sudo port install py-rpy2               # seemed to be fine. A 
$ python -m 'rpy2.tests'                  # gave the output 
usr/bin/python: No module named rpy2 
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.7 -m 'rpy2.tests # results in a 
'Segmentation fault'                      # and MacOS is complaining..
```

After upgrading all outdated packages and

```
$ sudo port -f uninstall py-rpy2  
$ sudo port -f install py-rpy2
... the same as above.<br>

$ sudo easy_install rpy2
```

throws many errors and ends with

```
'error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1'
```

You can find full output [here](http://boltzmann.office-on-the.net/~stefan/easy_install_rpy2.log).

I have only a

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/
```

path, 2.7 has no

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

entry.

```
localhost:~$ ls /opt/local/bin/python* 
/opt/local/bin/python2.4       
/opt/local/bin/python3.3 /opt/local/bin/python2.6       
/opt/local/bin/python3.3-config /opt/local/bin/python2.6-config
/opt/local/bin/pythonw2.6 /opt/local/bin/python2.7       
/opt/local/bin/pythonw2.7 /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config
/opt/local/bin/pythonw3.3

$ which python 
'/usr/bin/python'
```

This one is Python 2.6.1.